# How do I iterate a JSON list?

Tags: javascript, java, list, format

I have the following list in java

```
for (SilError error : silMessagesException.getFormattedInformations()) {
    msgInfo.add(error.getErrorMessage());
}
JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(msgInfo);
mav.addObject("information", jsArray);
```

I cannot seem to iterate the list `information` in javascript like this:

```
var json ='${information}';

for (var key in json) {
    alert (key)
}
});
```

The alert returns the numbers 1, 2, 3 ...

Comment: Post your json variable

Comment: You have a list in java and are trying to iterate it with javascript? The two languages are not the same.

Comment: Can you post the results of printing your Java magInfo variable and its type?

Comment: Is a string variable whith twho elements ["Attention, la quantité facturée est nulle.", "Message OK"]

Answer (score 3):

**for...in** returns the **index** of the value, not the value itself.

Try:

```
for (var key in json) {
        alert (json[key]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Its simply. Now you have the keys, You can use them like:

```
for (var key in json) {
    alert.log("Key: " + key + " has value: " + json[key])
    }
});
```

Comment: This solution returns : Key: 0 has value: [

Comment: Hope you liked it and found it usefull :)